# Apache Beam pipeline not running task in parallel using Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-beam

I am just getting started with Apache Beam using Python. I have a task I wish to run in parallel but for some reason it runs in serial. Is there something I have completely misunderstand?

In the following example I want `RunInParallel` to execute simultaneously. The `DoFn` takes 2 seconds to process so I'd expect the following pipeline to finish in 2 seconds. However it takes 5 times 2 seconds .

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import time
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class RunInParallel(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(2)
        return [int(time.time())]


p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())
(p
 | 'Create tasks' >> beam.Create([i for i in range(5)])
 | "Run task" >> beam.ParDo(RunInParallel())
 | "Print timestamp" >> beam.Map(print)
 )

# Run the pipeline
res = p.run()
```

Output for the above pipeline is

```
1573065709
1573065711
1573065713
1573065715
1573065717
```

Comment: Are you using the `DirectRunner`? If so, can you test changing the [`parallelism`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/#execution-mode)?